# Mouse scale implementation, centered to mouse position [Algorithmic]

Tags: algorithm, geometry

how to implement a zoom in/out center on mouse position ?

For exemple (in a 1D exemple)

```
C the position of the center (C = 3)
M the point where the zoom is applied (M = 5)
[___] represent the screen

[__C_M___]
after a zoom in, I increment the zoomFactor and it render like that :
[__C__M__]
but I'll like to render like that (The point M dont move): 
[_C__M___]
```

which offset I need to apply to the center to get this display ?

in this simple exemple, it's -1

thanks in advance

[Edit : Add my code]

```java
public void zoomCallback(boolean zoomUp, Point origine) {
      // origine is the mouse position relatively to the screen
      if ((zoomLevel == 0.75 && !zoomUp) || (zoomLevel == 3 && zoomUp))
         return;
      zoomLevel *= zoomUp ? 1.25 : 0.75;
      zoomLevel = Math.max(0.75, zoomLevel);
      zoomLevel = Math.min(3, zoomLevel);
      // zoomLevel is used the scale the map when displaying it
      Point mapCenter = this.getMapCenter();
      // the map center is juste the position of map center relatively to the screen
      this.mapOffset.translate(/* ??? , ??? */);
      // the mapOffset is used to print the map on the screen
   }
```

Comment: Post your current code - it makes it easier to explain what needs to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the calculation of the offset:

```
oldDistance = M - C
oldZoomLevel = zoomLevel
"Apply the zoomLevel modification"
newDistance = oldDistance * zoomLevel / oldZoomLevel
offset = oldDistance - newDistance
```

for the code :

```java
double old_xDistanceToCenter = (origine.getX() - getMapCenter().getX());
double old_yDistanceToCenter = (origine.getY() - getMapCenter().getY());
double oldZoomLevel = zoomLevel;

zoomLevel += zoomUp ? 0.25 : -0.25;
zoomLevel = Math.max(0.75, zoomLevel);
zoomLevel = Math.min(3, zoomLevel);

double xDistanceToCenter = old_xDistanceToCenter * zoomLevel / oldZoomLevel;
double yDistanceToCenter = old_yDistanceToCenter * zoomLevel / oldZoomLevel;

this.mapOffset.translate(
     (int) Math.round(old_xDistanceToCenter - xDistanceToCenter),
     (int) Math.round(old_yDistanceToCenter - yDistanceToCenter)
);
```